# how can i decoding to UDP fragmentation packages header ?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

My application is listen to some UDP multicast.
This multicast is sent message - and this message size is very big ( ~9500000 bytes ).

I don't know how the UDP sender work because this is not code on my control.
But the sender using fragmentation to send all the packages.

I using wireshark to see the packages and on the header of any message i see flag that tell me if this package is the last one or if there are more packages after this one.

I trying on my code to decoding the message header - and i fail any time to do it.

I try to use the Encoding.ASCII & Encoding.Unicode - but this is not working and i can't tell when i finish to collect all the packages from the fragmentation.

any help please ...

How wireshark see it and can Decoding the header ?

Comment: *i can't tell when i finish to collect all the packages from the fragmentation.* **is the opposite of** *on the header of any message i see flag that tell me if this package is the last one or if there are more packages after this one*

Comment: The headers of the various layered protocols are handled by your network card and device drivers. On socket level you only get the transported data. The udp and ip headers are not included. The fragmentation and defragmentation should be handled by this lower layers so you should not have to worry about. With Tcp you get a stream abstraction for your connection. With Udp I'm not sure.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618917/receiving-packets-in-udp . If sender sent a packet (of any size, can be fragmented), you'll receive a single packet (or you won't receive anything)

Comment: xanatos - this is not right ... i see on the code that this is just wrong.

Comment: people this message is more than 64k IP can handle fragmentation only up to 64k.

Comment: @xanatos only if the packet is smaller than 64k because then the fragmentation is done at IP layer.

Comment: other than that the OP has to show some code.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck You are right (on all the three comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

I don't have access to IP or UDP headers (apart from the remote host's IP address) directly from a "normal" Socket or UdpClient, only to the data being transmitted (the "payload"). The underlying networking machinery takes care of that.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8723498d-c276-4bb4-9d2d-9211ce5d7487/parse-udp-headers

So i can't know if the  fragmentation package is finished.