# what are the possible UDP data transfer errors?

Tags: sockets, udp, client-server

we're going to develop a game with internet multiplayer support. since it's an interactive game I know I have to use UDP to reduce connection latency, but I'm wondering what are the possible errors that may occur in a package delivered using UDP connection? everywhere I looked they say UDP provides "Best effort delivery", but no one does give a complete explanation what does it mean. after reading some article there are two questions that I still have:

1. Is it possible to send a package and receive part of it at the other end of connection?
2. if your answer to first quesiton is true what would happen to the next packages? should I wait for the rest of package or can I assume next package start with my next `recv` call?

for our game I think we will need to send 4 packages of around 20 byte each second.

Comment: If possible, try to combine those four packages into one. The overhead will be smaller.

Comment: I presume "packet" is meant instead of "package" or a message than can be fragmented over many packets?

Comment: Consider you have guarantees on minimum packet size which allows you to send more information per update:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1098897/175849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common thing that can happen is: one side sends a message, the other receives nothing.

> Is it possible to send a package and receive part of it at the other
>   end of connection?

Not really, not even when the message is huge and it gets fragmented. Unlike in `TCP`, in `UDP` every message is independent. You either get it entirely or nothing at all.

So what you should do it just `recvfrom` things in a loop and process them. Obviously you should make your application impervious to message loss such that a missing message doesn't crash it.

Comment: On Linux with [UDPlite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_Lite) you can receive partial packets, useful for streaming video, useless for pretty much everything else.