# Java DatagramPacket (UDP) maximum send/recv buffer size

Tags: java, udp

In Java when using [`DatagramPacket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) suppose you have a `byte[1024*1024]` buffer.  If you just pass that for the DatagramPacket when sending/receiving will a Java receive call for the DatagramPacket block until it has read the entire megabyte?

I'm asking if Java will split it up or just try to send the entire thing which gets dropped.

Normally the size limit is around 64KB for a UDP packet, but I wondered since Java's API allow for byte arrays if that is a limit and something super huge is dropped or split up and reassembled for you.

If it is dropped what API call would tell me the maximum data payload I can use in the Java call?  I've heard that IPv6 also has jumbo frames, but does DatagramPacket (or [`DatagramSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html)) support that since UDP defines the header spec?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`DatagramPacket` is just a wrapper on a UDP based socket, so the usual UDP rules apply.

64 kilobytes is the theoretical maximum size of a complete IP datagram, but only 576 bytes are guaranteed to be routed.  On any given network path, the link with the smallest Maximum Transmit Unit will determine the actual limit.  (1500 bytes, less headers is the common maximum, but it is impossible to predict how many headers there will be so its safest to limit messages to around 1400 bytes.)

If you go over the MTU limit, IPv4 will automatically break the datagram up into fragments and reassemble them at the end, but only up to 64 kilobytes and only if all fragments make it through.  If any fragment is lost, or if any device decides it doesn't like fragments, then the entire packet is lost.

As noted above, it is impossible to know in advance what the MTU of path will be.  There are various algorithms for experimenting to find out, but many devices do not properly implement (or deliberately ignore) the necessary standards so it all comes down to trial and error.  Or you can just guess 1400 bytes per message.

As for errors, if you try to send more bytes than the OS is configured to allow, you should get an `EMSGSIZE` error or its equivalent.  If you send less than that but more than the network allows, the packet will just disappear.

Comment: Actually, the minimum guaranteed MTU for IPv4 across the network is only 68 Byte - 576 is the minimum that hosts are required to handle. Either way, such a small MTU would be really, really unusual.

Comment: Does that mean if you have a packet size greater than 64KB, you'd use a different protocol?

Comment: @PhaniRahul: I would say that it means "thank you God that the protocol handles segmentation transparently and makes my data into as many packets as are needed". I doubt if any practical protocols in use will give you larger packet sizes. :)

Comment: FYI: Minimum MTU of IPv6 packet: 1280

Comment: @lxgr The minimum is 576 as per RFC 1122. 'Hosts' includes routers.

Comment: @PhaniRahul - Frankly UDP messages that are significantly larger than the MTU are not practical.  Given the probability of a packet loss is P, do the math to work out the probability of the loss of one or more of the N packets in a large UDP message.  (Hint: look up the birthday paradox.)

Answer (score 0):

java.net.DatagramPacket buffer max size is 65507.

See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure

Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) size varies dependent on implementation but is arguably irrelevant to the basic question "Java DatagramPacket (UDP) maximum send/recv buffer size" as the MTU is transparent to the java.net.DatagramPacket layer.

Answer (score -1):

@ Mihai Danila. Because I couldn't add a comment to the above answer, that's why writing into reply section.

In continuation of your answer on MTU size, in my practice, I try to use `NetworkInterface.getMTU()-40` for setting the buffer size of `DatagramSocket.setSendBufferSize()`. So, trying not to rely on `getSendBufferSize()` This is to make sure it matches different window sizes on different platforms and is universally acceptable on ethernet (ignoring dial-up for a moment). I haven't hardcoded it to 1460 bytes (1500-20-20) because on windows, the MTU size is universally 1500. However, windows platform's own window size is 8192 bytes, but I believe, by setting the SO_SNDBUF to < MTU, I am burdening the network/IP layer less, and for all the hops for routers and receivers, some overheads. Thus, reducing some latency over the network.

Similarly, for the receive buffer, I am using a max of 64K or 65535 bytes. This way my program is portable on different platforms using different window sizes.

Do you think it sounds OK? I have not implemented any tools to measure any differences but assuming that its the case based on what's out there.

Comment: There is no point in setting a small buffer size. You are not 'burdening the network IP layer less' or 'reducing some latency' at all. Set it big, or just leave it alone if you don't know what you're doing. But make sure you don't *send* anything too large. There is no 'window size' in UDP. Do you mean MTU?

Comment: @EJP. There are many posts on the web that clearly mention that fragmentation adds overhead to the network/routers. Check http://pedrotrigueira.net/?page_id=163 as an example. BY setting the size of the SO_SNDBUF <= MTU, you are avoiding that overhead of fragmentation and reassembly. You are right that UDP doesnt have to deal with platform's windows size at the transport layer, but if the packet is larger than the window size of the platform, it would be delivered truncated to transport layer. So, you cant send a 64K packet.

Comment: By setting `SO_SNDBUF <= MTU` you are preventing yourself from sending datagrams any larger, but you are also preventing UDP from buffering outgoing datagrams even if they're of an acceptable size, and thereby blocking your sending code unduly. It is the *size of the `send()`* that determines the size of the datagram, and you should keep *that* < MTU. If you don't send them too big, they won't be too big, no matter how big your `SO_SNDBUF` is. I'm not much interested in arbitrary 3rd-party blogs as citations, but yours doesn't say a word about `SO_SNDBUF`, so it doesn't support your case.

Comment: @EJP, I posted the link of a 3rd party only to let you know that even if you are sending a large UDP packet through your application (thus application layer), then, based on window size (for example, Windows has a 8192 bytes) it will be delivered in that form to IP layer, which will then fragment it to 1480 bytes each of IP packet size with common ID, fragment offset, etc in the IP header. Since most network use ethernet today, the MTU < 1500 and many of these fragments arrive out of order to the router, which then assembles and sends further to the destination, which again reassembles

Comment: @EJP. In continuation to my above comment...so, even though UDP doesnt know if the packet was fragmented before its delivery to the application, the packet went through many hops and thus many fragmentation and rassemblies. This adds to the overheads on the network and thus, the sender's packet size does matter for overall efficiency of applications that are time sensitive. Now, you dont have to do to 3rd party to read this, you can go to IP /UDP rfcs for more clarification. This doesnt matter for TCP, because its a streaming protocol and 1 byte is OK at the application layer.

Comment: @EJP, In most cases, you program will work, but it will have comparatively lower efficiency on networks. So, as a best practice its better to use the size <MTU. I have mentioned SO_SNDBUF in my comment.

Comment: @EJP, I would also suggest that you should try to test this using wireshark on both client and server and it will visually display the packet fragmentation and reassembly at the network level to you. try sending a for example, a 5K packet and see for yourself what I just explained holds true. No 3rd parties to verify.

Comment: I am familiar with IP fragmentation, thanks, and it doesn't have any bearing on your answer. Socket send and receive buffers should be made as large as you can afford, and there should certainly be no attempt to relate them to the MTU. It is making them *too small* that increases fragementation, so making them bigger *reduces* it. Surely this is obvious? NB I have provided no 'program' so I have no idea what you mean by 'your program will work', but if you're referring to my *recommendation* as stated here, it will work in all cases, not just 'most cases'.