# What to do about UDP packets arriving in pieces

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

I have a Java application that is receiving UDP packets in a loop:

```
while (running) {
    try {
        // Block until a packet is received on the port
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(byteIn);

        // Print packet
        String packetString = "";
        while((packetString = dataIn.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("WiFi", packetString);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d("WiFi", "Problem receiving: " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

When I get packets, many of them arrive as expected, but every once in a while, I get a packet that is broken up into two pieces:

```
103, -5.84, 5.64, 140.72, #A-=-22.53,-50.18,248.83,  #G-=52.00,-69.00,-18.00,   #M-=-146.66,-155.18,151.06,   2575012
103, -6.51, 5.62, 140.41, #A-=-22.53,-51.20,248.83,  #G-=23.00,44.00,-7.00,   #M-=-146.21,-156.13,151.06,   2575036
103, -7.23, 5.65, 140.09, #A-=-19.46,-49.15,243.71,  #G-=17.00,68.00,-2.00,   #M-=-144.85,-155.18,151.06,   2575063
103, -7.76, 5.60, 139.81, #A-=-17.41,-50.18,240.64,  #G-=17.00,71.00,0.00,   #M-=-143.94,-155.65,153
.47,   2575090
103, -8.51, 5.34, 139.40, #A-=-12.29,-47.10,233.47,  #G-=31.00,-1.00,-5.00,   #M-=-144.85,-154.70,151.87,   2575135
103, -9.20, 4.76, 138.95, #A-=-15.36,-50.18,239.62,  #G-=22.00,30.00,-3.00,   #M-=-146.66,-156.13,151.87,   2575200
103, -9.82, 4.46, 138.61, #A-=-15.36,-47.10,239.62,  #G-=33.00,1.00,-3.00,   #M-=-145.76,-156.13,152.27,   2575266
103, -10.38, 4.07, 138.23, #A-=-14.34,-48.13,235.52,  #G-=30.00,4.00,-7.00,   #M-=-144.85,-155.65,152.27,   2575372
103, -10.90, 3.76, 137.90, #A-=-14.34,-48.13,237.57,  #G-=29.00,19.00,-4.00,   #M-=-145.30,-156.13,151.47,   2575520
103, -11.41, 3.53, 137.44, #A-=-15.36,-48.13,235.52,  #G-=25.00,18.00,-4.00,   #M-=-146.21,-155.18,151.47,   2576917
```

As you can see on lines 4 and 5, the last trailing characters of 4 have been cut off and a new packet of the remaining characters have arrived. From my reading about UDP, everyone warns that UDP does not guarantee the arrival of packets. In my case that is not a problem; a dropped packet hear or there isn't going to break my application. However, I haven't found anything about packets not necessarily arriving as complete. In fact, I have read that this **does not** happen.

How is this dealt with usually? It is difficult for me to know if a packet that has arrived is complete or not in which I could just wait for the next packet and append the data.

Comment: Since IP-level fragmentation is supposed to be undone in the IP stack before you see the packets, I suspect the server is sending the data in two packets.  Your best bet is to replicate the condition while watching the traffic with Wireshark to see what's _actually_ going on.  There are enough different moving parts here (server, network, OS, TCP/IP stack, etc) that you're not likely to get much further without seeing the network traffic on the wire.

Comment: I downloaded WireShark and I am looking at the packets. I haven't used WireShark before and right now I am in fiddling mode. What looks to be happening is that a standard packet is about 156 bytes, but sometimes it combines these into a larger packet (I am assuming that the OS is implementing some kind of buffer? This happens when there is frequent traffic) up to 492 bytes. [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203403/java-datagrampacket-udp-maximum-buffer-size) implies I am hitting the limit. What is usually done about this?

Comment: No, that refers to transport-layer fragmentation.  At the application layer, either the entire packet arrives at the destination or it doesn't.  UDP will never combine multiple source datagrams into a single IP packet.  You're going to have to match Wireshark traces to debug output and recreate the condition to see what is being sent. Pay attention to the IP fragmentation flags; Wireshark tells you when fragments are detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is impossible. UDP datagrams arrive intact and complete or not at all. The server must be sending the data in two datagrams.

Comment: After doing some digging, it turns out that the chip I was using to send UDP packets (the WiFly Rn-Xv) was automatically bundling data into larger packets and then splitting into multiple packets when the larger packet grew to large. I am assuming this was done to cut down on overhead. I solved my problem by adding a special character to the start of my string and a special character to the end of my string so that I could check if a packet contained a full amount of data. If it didn't, I could append a new packet on.