# Datagram packages size limits

Tags: java, networking, bit, datagram

What I want to do with a program I'm writing in Java, is give the users the ability to talk to the "server" program using Datagram Packages.

The only problem is, for the server to send back the information the client just asked for, its sending back huge amounts of text. When I learned about Datagram Packages, it always told me to make packages with a 256 bit size. Why is that? Is there a better way to send the data? Or do I have to just deal with sending the data in multiple messages of 256 bits?

Comment: Do you mean datagram packets?

Comment: Why not start off with some [reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol).

Comment: *"When I learned about Datagram Packages, it always told me to make packages with a 256 bit size."* - You either misread that, or someone taught you incorrectly.  The recommended limit is 534 BYTES.  It is always a good idea to check these things from a definitive source ... rather than relying on (possibly faulty) knowledge / memory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098897/what-is-the-largest-safe-udp-packet-size-on-the-internet

Answer (score 2):

The generally accepted practical limit for a UDP datagram is 534 bytes or so, as all hosts and routers are required not to fragment below this size. The maximum possible value in IPv4 is 65507 bytes, but that won't get through even one router: it may not even get *into* the sender's socket send buffer, let alone onto the network.

I don't know where you got 256 from, but you can certainly double it. And it's bytes, not bits.