# C# UDP sendto buffer

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, buffer

Im making an app that will be sending data of 1MB length. Bellow is my testing code which is just sending a simple byte array of 1MB, However it keeps throwing the bellow exception even when I try increasing the send buffer to 1MB or above.

Code

```
private void sendattack(string ip, int port)
    {
        IPEndPoint RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        Socket serversoc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        char[] data = new char[100000];
        var send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        serversoc.SendTo(send, send.Length, SocketFlags.None, RemoteEndPoint);
    }
```

Error

> A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled
>     ErrorCode=10040
>     HResult=-2147467259
>     Message=A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself
>     NativeErrorCode=10040
>     Source=System
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendTo(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, EndPoint remoteEP)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendTo(Byte[] buffer, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, EndPoint remoteEP)
>          at qnet.svchost.sendattack(String ip, Int32 port) in C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\qnet\qnet\svchost.cs:line 84
>          at qnet.svchost.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\qnet\qnet\svchost.cs:line 27
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>     InnerException:

Comment: UDP Packet size is 65507 bytes, for pure windows networking and much smaller otherwise. Then for 1Mb packets, switch to TCP.

Answer (score 3):

The error is self-explanatory: You cannot send a packet that large.  The theoretical maximum size of a UDP packet is about 64KB, and the size that will be safely sent over the internet without fragmentation is less than 1KB:  [What is the largest Safe UDP Packet Size on the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098897/what-is-the-largest-safe-udp-packet-size-on-the-internet)

You need to make things smaller.

Comment: So would it be best to split into smaller packets of 10KB and send them separately?

Comment: Yes, or something like that; you'll have to handle breaking down your data into smaller pieces at a higher level.  Remember that on reassembly, there's no guarantee that the packets will come out in the same order that they were sent; so that's another complication to deal with.

Comment: The problem with splitting UDP packets is that UDP doesn't grant reception of all packets, what may lead to implement a recovery mechanism.