# Scapy not sending big UDP packets

Tags: python, networking, udp, scapy

I try to send a UDP packet via scapy, but when I try to send something a bit big (e.g 1800 chars of Raw load) it doesn't send it at all.

```
def send_info(info):
    msg = IP(dst=MANAGER_IP) / UDP(dport = MANAGER_PORT) / \
    Raw(load = ("AAAAAAAAAAAA" + info)) #for some reason it throws out the first 12 charaters
    print("Sending...")
    send(msg, verbose=False)
    print("Sent!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum UDP packet size is around 1500 bytes on many systems and networks, even less on the public internet.

See [What is the largest Safe UDP Packet Size on the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098897/what-is-the-largest-safe-udp-packet-size-on-the-internet)