# What is the maximum number of bytes WSARecv can receive at one time?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2, iocp

I'm using std::vector to represent a buffer in my per IO data structure:

```
struct PerIoData 
{
    WSAOVERLAPPED m_overlapped;
    SOCKET m_socket;
    WSABUF m_wsaBuf;
    std::vector<BYTE> m_vecBuffer;
    DWORD m_dwFlags;
    DWORD m_dwNumberOfBytesSent;
    DWORD m_dwNumberOfBytesToSend;
    eOperationType m_operationType;
};

...
...
if (WSARecv(pPerIoData->m_socket, &(pPerIoData->m_wsaBuf), 1, &dwNumberOfBytesReceived, &(pPerIoData->m_dwFlags), &(pPerIoData->m_overlapped), NULL) == 0)
    continue;
```

I want to specify the maximum size and perform "shrink to fit" on m_vecBuffer after calling WSARecv().

I've had a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but been unable to find the information I'm looking for.

Comment: Would that not require a memory deallocation?  I try to avoid such things in network servers.  I use plain arrays and never resize them.  I don't know what the maximum size is, but it's more than 256K.  Quite possibly it's 4G on 32-bit system, (OK, unlikely in practice:).

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2862176/1496544).

Comment: @Littlegator-Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WSABUF` struct that you pass to `WSARecv()` specifies a pointer to a buffer that `WSARecv()` reads the bytes into, and the maximum number of bytes that can be read into that buffer.  When `WSARecv()` completes its work, it reports how many bytes were actually read into the buffer.  If you use the `vector` as the buffer, you have to pre-allocate the vector to whatever max size you want, then set `WSABUF::buf` to point at the vector's internal memory, set `WSABUF::len` to the vector's allocated size, and then resize the vector to the new value that `WSARecv()` reports.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm going to do.  Cheers Remy.