net.PacketConn ReadFrom, how to distinguish packets
The documentation for net.PacketConn ReadFrom method states that it reads a packet from the connection.
If my buffer is smaller than a packet how do I know the packet boundaries?
I thought of the case when I can check the number of bytes read and when they are less than the buffer size to assume end of the packet. But this is not reliable because the packet length can equal my buffer length.
For the UDP case this function goes down to the recvfrom system call in linux.
This system call returns a flag MSG_EOR to indicate end of record/packet read.
But I don't see how this is reflected in go.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704680/read-data-from-a-udp-socket-with-an-unknown-length/24705791#24705791

It is strange that so important information regarding discarding the trailing bytes is missing from the documentation.

that is system level documentation, not really related to Go. As I mentioned in my other answer, you really need to understand the underlying protocols and APIs. The TCP conn for example doesn’t go into depth on the connection semantics because it’s assumed that the user understands TCP even though it might help the occasional user who is unaware. You would end up with documentation that is far too dense and broad to be of service to the majority of users.
