# read buff in tcp socket

Tags: c, sockets, buffer, recv

I read [How large should my recv buffer be when calling recv in the socket library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862071/how-large-should-my-recv-buffer-be-when-calling-recv-in-the-socket-library) in order to understand buffer in read. There are yet some points that i wish to know about read buffer in tcp socket connection.
My application is sending video packets. when i set buff to 80000 sender could send the packets but when i set it less for example 8000 after sending few packets it stops with RST.

a)Is this buffer, TCP receive window?
b)Is there any relation between this buffer and .net.ipv4.tcp_rmem , .net.ipv4.tcp_wmem ?if yes, Should i set read buffer based on rmem or wmem?

I would greatly appreciate any responses

Comment: (a) No, in the code shown in your link it is the application buffer, a char array. If that's not what you're talking about it is up to you to clarify. (b) No. If you got a reset just by changing the buffer size there is something wrong with your code. Hard to see why you would reduce the buffer size, whichever buffer you're talking about. More is better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got what buff is doing now. I will write a new question about how to solve the problem of RST in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a)Is this buffer, TCP receive window?

No, it is just a buffer that you provide for the TCP stack to place bytes into when you call recv().

> b)Is there any relation between this buffer and .net.ipv4.tcp_rmem ,
>   .net.ipv4.tcp_wmem?

No.

> if yes, Should i set read buffer based on rmem or women?

You can pass any size buffer you want to recv(); it is unrelated to any of the above, except that there isn't any benefit to making the buffer you pass to recv() larger than the socket's current SO_RCVBUF size, since it's unlikely that recv() would ever return more bytes at once than can be present in the socket's internal buffer.

As for how to decide what size buffer to use -- consider that a larger buffer will (of course) take up more memory, and if you are allocating that buffer on the stack, a very large buffer might cause a stack overflow.  On the other hand, a smaller buffer means that you can read fewer bytes with any given call to recv(), so you may have to call recv() more times to read in the same total number of bytes.

Note that number of bytes of data returned by recv() may be any number from 1 byte up to the total size of the buffer that you passed in to recv()'s third argument, and there is no way to predict how many bytes you'll get.  In particular, with TCP the number of bytes you receive from any particular call to recv() will *not* have any correlation to the number of bytes previously passed to any particular call to send() on the sending side.  So you just need to use a "reasonably sized" array (for whatever definition of "reasonably sized" you prefer) and recv() as many bytes into it as possible, and then handle that many bytes (based on recv()'s return value).

Comment: See the link. 'This buffer' is an application-side char array, not the TCP socket receive buffer.