# Data Corrupted When Reading from Byte Stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, python-3.7

For a networking project, I'm using UDP Multicast to build an overlay network with my own implementation of IP.

I use the following to parse and build my Header first, then append the payload:

```
def __init__(buffer_size_bytes):
    self.__buffer = bytearray(buffer_size_bytes)

def read_sock(self, listening_socket):
    n_bytes, addr = listening_socket.recvfrom_into(self.__buffer, Packet.HEADER_SIZE)
    packet = Packet.parse_header(self.__buffer)

    if packet.payload_length is not 0:
        packet.payload = parse_payload(packet.payload_length, listening_socket)

    self.__router.add_to_route_queue(packet, listening_socket.locator)

def parse_payload(to_read, socket):
    payload = bytearray(to_read)
    view = memoryview(payload)
    while to_read:
        n_bytes, addr = socket.recvfrom_into(view, to_read)
        view = view[n_bytes:]
        to_read -= n_bytes

    return payload
```

The header seems to be parsed correctly, but the payload gets corrupted every time. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong when parsing the payload, and I can confirm I'm sending a bytearray from the other side.

For example, when I send a packet with the payload "Hello World" encoded in utf-8, I receive the following:

```
b'`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00'
```

The Packet.parse_header method:

```
def parse_header(cls, packet_bytes):
    values = struct.unpack(cls.ILNPv6_HEADER_FORMAT, packet_bytes[:cls.HEADER_SIZE])

    flow_label = values[0] & 1048575
    traffic_class = (values[0] >> 20 & 255)
    version = values[0] >> 28
    payload_length = values[1]
    next_header = values[2]
    hop_limit = values[3]
    src = (values[4], values[5])
    dest = (values[6], values[7])

    return Packet(src, dest, next_header, hop_limit, version, traffic_class, flow_label, payload_length)
```

For reference, the entire sent packet looks like this:

```
b'`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01Hello World'
```

On receiving the first packet, the socket.recvfrom_into blocks when reading for the payload, and doesn't return until I send another message. It then seems to discard the payload of the previous message and use the second packet received as the payload...

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to repro this. Can you show the actual `bytes` before and after corruption?

Comment: Are you sure the header is parsed correctly? The `\x0b` in the string is 11 which is also `len("Hello World")`.

Comment: @tripleee I should've looked at the full sent bytes not just the payload! What I'm receiving as the payload on the other end appears to be the start of the actual packet rather than the payload

Comment: @David The header is parsed correctly, but when I read from the socket, it doesn't seem to be "getting rid of" the already read data (the header), so I'm reading it again as the payload.

Comment: @JordanMackie And do you really read from the socket twice? And do you get a fresh destination buffer for the parsing of the payload?

Comment: @David Definitely read from the socket twice, definitely get a fresh destination buffer for the parsing of the payload.

Comment: Can you please update the question and provide the code which parses the header?

Comment: @David added the header parsing code. It just struct.unpacks from the given byte array. Size of 40 bytes. Also added all of the bytes that are sent.

Comment: Your `parse_payload` takes three args but you call it with two? (At least in the example.)

Comment: @David my bad, that was a leftover of me trying something else before asking SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862071/how-large-should-my-recv-buffer-be-when-calling-recv-in-the-socket-library).

So the key thing was that I'm using UDP. And UDP sockets discard anything that doesn't fit in the buffer you give it.

TCP sockets however behave more like the bytestream I was expecting.

Fun!