# implementing ack over UDP?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, udp, network-protocols

We have a system (built in C) in place that performs communication over UDP.  Recently we have found a necessity to guarantee delivery of packets.  My question is: what would be the minimum additions to a UDP based system to ensure delivery using ack packets?  Also, ideally without having to manipulate the packet headers.  We have application level control over the packets including sequence numbers and ack/nack flags.  I am wondering if this is a lost cause and anything we attempt to do will basically be a flawed and broken version of TCP.  Basically, is there a minimalist improvement we can make to achieve guaranteed delivery (we do not need many features of TCP such as congestion control etc.).  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's worth it? Simply using a proven technology vs. a homebrew system. Is the performance benefit clear or you're just prematurely optimizing?

Comment: The system is real-time and already conforms to the spec which calls for UDP.

Answer (score 11):

TCP intertwines 3 services that might be relevant (okay TCP does a lot more, but I'm only going to talk about 3.)

1. In-order delivery
2. Reliable delivery
3. Flow control

You just said that you don't need flow control, so I won't even address that (how you would advertise a window size, etc. well, except that you'll probably need a window. i'll get to it.)

You did say that you need reliable delivery. That isn't too hard - you use ACKs to show that the sender has received a packet. Basic reliable delivery looks like:

1. Sender sends the packet
2. Receiver receives packet, and then sends an ack
3. If the sender doesn't get an ack (by way of a timer), he resends the packet.

Those three steps don't address these issues:

1. What if the ACK gets lost?
2. What if packets arrive out of order?

So for your application, you said you only needed reliable delivery - but didn't say anything about needing them in order. This will affect the way you implement your protocol.

(example where in-order doesn't matter: you're copying employee records from one computer to another. doesn't matter if Alice's record is received before Bob's, as long as both get there.)

So going on the presumption that you only need reliable (since that's what you said in your post), you could achieve this several ways.

Your sender can keep track of unacknowledged packets. So if it sends # 3, 4, 5, and 6, and doesn't get an ACK for 3 and 4, then the sender knows that it needs to retransmit. (Though the sender doesn't know if packets 3 and 4 were lots, or if their ACKs were lost. Either way, we have to retransmit.)

But then your sender could do cumulative ACKs - so in the above example, it would only ack #6 if it had received 3, 4, and 5. This means that the receiver would *drop* packet 6 if it hadn't received the ones before. If your network is very reliable, then this might not be a bad option.

The protocols described above, however, do have a window - that is, how many packets does the sender send at once? Which means that you do need some sort of windowing, but not for the purpose of flow control. How'll you transmit window sizes?

You could do it without a window by either having the window size constant, or by doing something like stop-and-wait. The former might be a better option.

Anyway, I haven't directly answered your question, but I hope I've pointed out some of the things that are worth considering when architecting this. The task of having "reliable transfer" without parts of flow control (like windowing) and without any regard to in-order is hard! (Let me know if I should give more details about some of this stuff!)

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Chapter 8 and Chapter 20 of Steven's [UNIX Network Programming, volume 1](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html). He covers a number of different approaches.  Section 20.5 "Adding Reliability to a UDP Application" is probably most interesting to you.

Comment: +1 for a great reference.  When previously doing something similar for a programming assignment, that section was great.

Answer (score 4):

I have a question running [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107668/what-do-you-use-when-you-need-reliable-udp) which is collecting answers to "What to you use when you need reliable UDP". The answers are possibly much more than you want or need but you might be able to take a look at some of the protocols that have been built on UDP and grab just the ACK part that you need.

From my work with the ENet protocol (a reliable UDP protocol), I expect that you need a sequence number in each UDP datagram, a way of sending an ACK for datagrams that you've received, a way of keeping hold of datagrams that you've sent until you get an ACK for them or they time out and a way of timing the resending of datagrams for which you have yet to receive an ACK... I would also add an overall timeout for when you decide that you are never going to deliver a particular datagram, and, I guess, a callback to your application layer to inform it of this failure to deliver...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement ack is to do it in the application layer. CoAP is an example of an application protocol which runs on udp but provides reliable data transfer. It keeps a message id for all the Confirmable(CON) messages and sends an receiver sends an ack packet with the same message id. All the ack and message id fields are kept at the application layer part. So if the sender doesn't receive an Ack packet with the message id send by him, it re transmits that packet. Application developer can modify the protocol to suit the needs required for reliable data transfer .

Answer (score 0):

Tough problem. I would say, you wont be able to achieve the reliability of TCP. However, i do understand that sometimes, you need to have reliable UDP.

[Gamedev forum](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=46637)

[RUDP](http://www.javvin.com/protocolRUDP.html) (a bit more hardcore)

[Old Thread about reliable UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107668/what-do-you-use-when-you-need-reliable-udp)