# C++ multiplayer UDP socket API

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, multiplayer

Can anyone recommend an easy to use, fast and reliable C++ API for sending and receiving data over a UDP socket? Maybe something that is specifcally intended for multiplayer games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raknet is amazingly good. So good that is the basis for networking in commercial engines like unity3d. http://www.jenkinssoftware.com

Comment: This one's packed with features!

Comment: I really like this one, as according to the site, it has some security features as well as an updater etc!

Comment: I've decided to give RakNet a whirl, it seems very well documented, and has a lot of features that I can benefit from. Not saying the other implementations suggested are bad, I just decided to pick this library. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 7):

It's not specifically for gaming, but if you want to get down to the metal and implement your own protocol over UDP, [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is really nice.

Comment: I second this. When I chose enet, boost.asio was not yet released, but it's a great choice.

Comment: But does boost.asio give you anything but cross platform async I/O ? Surely this question is asking for more than that?

Comment: @Len: I'm well aware of what asio provides, but the way the question was asked (specifically the "... Maybe ..." part) I figured Boost.Asio could be an interesting choice in case existing frameworks did not fulfill all needs

Comment: I think I just read the question as asking for more than just a way to send udp using C++, but that might just have been my reading of the question.

Comment: Actually, boost is a horrible choice if you want to 'get down to the metal'. *Great* choice if your looking for a high level, easy to use asio pattern - but very limited from a bare metal perspective.

Answer (score 5):

[enet](http://enet.bespin.org/) suits your needs

- simple
- fast
- reliable UDP
- intended for real time multiplayer games

It's not object-oriented though.

Comment: I suppose I could wrap it in a class if needed.

Comment: Enet is great if your looking for a low-level, reliable UDP solution. Has the useful bits of the TCP protocol without the bloat. Not just reliable, but also has flow control and congestion avoidance.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the answers to this question: [What do you use when you need reliable UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107668/what-do-you-use-when-you-need-reliable-udp). I developed a C++ version of ENet (which has a C API) for a client and they use it as the basis of their gaming middleware product.