# How to know the network packet status in Gstreamer

Tags: networking, gstreamer

I have created client and server application for live streaming using GStreamer.How I will know the network packet status it has been reached or failed to the destination?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot generally know whether a package has reached or not reached it's destination.

e.g. when using UDP (as in `udpsrc` & `udpsink`), there is - *by design* - no way to know whether the package reached it's destination.

otoh, when using TCP/IP (as in `tcpclientsink` & `tcpserversrc`) the protocol stack will guarantee the delivery of each package, unless the connection drops. in which case your side will get notified of an EOS.

Comment: Currently, I am using RTP/UDP for live streaming and I am considering the rtpbin statistics for each session.

Answer (score 0):

Even in the case of tcp feedback is not real time. I mean a successful send API on the server doesn't mean that the packet has reached client at that point of time. It may be still stuck in one of those congestion windows but it will reach client eventually !

This effect can be seen very evidently if u are connecting to a RTSP/RTP on TCP stream over a bad network connection.

Concepts like reliable UDP can be of some help here.

[What do you use when you need reliable UDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107668/what-do-you-use-when-you-need-reliable-udp)